# how to write this in C

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, ida

how to write this ASM code in C?

```
loc_536FB0:
mov cl, [eax]
cmp cl, ' '
jb short loc_536FBC
cmp cl, ','
jnz short loc_536FBF

loc_536FBC:
mov byte ptr [eax], ' '

loc_536FBF
mov cl, [eax+1]
inc eax
test cl, cl
jnz short loc_536FB0
```

I have figured out that it is a for loop counting to 23 then exiting.

Comment: have a look [here](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: should i ask there again then?

Comment: would make sense, indeed :)

Comment: ok then, i will ask there.

Comment: It seems like you've already reverse-engineered it, since you say you know what it does. So what's the problem? You don't know how to write a `for` loop in C?

Comment: i do know how to write a for loop in C but i dont know what this code does besides that it counts to 23 and quits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *str; // = value of eax
int i = 0;
while (str[i]) {
    if (str[i] < ' ' || str[i] == ',')
        str[i] = ' ';
    i++;
}
```

It traverses a c-string and replaces all characters below `' '` and commas `','` with a space `' '`. See an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif): characters "below" space are all the controll characters. The function probably wants to erase them to get a "clean" string. The string is passed via a pointer in eax.

I don't know what this would have to do with 23, but maybe this is what you got for some specific input while debugging.

Comment: Small nitpick: given the assembly code in the question it would be more accurately transcribed as a `do { } while();`, since the NULL terminator check is the last thing performed during each iteration.